# Pagination in CakePHP omits fields existing in model, coincident with Datatable Component?

Tags: database, cakephp, controller, pagination, datatables

There is a behavior I don't understand.

```
$test1 = $this->Post->find('all');
debug($test1);
```

It delivers the expected array of posts with all fields of the model for each post in that array:

```
id, field 1, field 2, field 3 ...
```

If I´m using the following syntax:

```
$test2 = $this->paginate('Post');
debug($test2);
```

It shows the expected array of posts only with some certain fields of the model for each post in that array:

```
id, field 2, field 5, field 14
```

Why does this output occur when using the `paginate()-method`? How do I get the same output for the `paginate()-method` like for the `find()-method`?

If any further code is needed, please tell me.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

I found out that my DataTable-Component I loaded here: https://github.com/cnizzdotcom/cakephp-datatable could have an influence on that weird behaviour. But I didn´t find out how yet ...

Comment: Please check if you used `fields` option during $paginate initialization.

Comment: Nope, it´s like: public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 5,
  'maxLimit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'Post.DATE' => 'asc',
        ),
    );

Comment: try this in your PostsController....$options = array('fields' => array('Post.*'));
$this->Post->recursive = 0;
$this->paginate = $options;
$posts = $this->paginate();
debug($posts);

Comment: @ScrappyCocco: I pasted your exact code into my controller and it still delivers only some fields. I have to expand my question because I found out it pretty surely has to do with a datatable-helper I installed which uses und changes the paginate() for itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Like I assumed the problem was the DataTable-Component. In the controller are multiple paginate() calls and the last one with its certain field-assignments was saved in the ´$this->paginate´ variable. So when I run Cakes normal pagination without setting fields, that variable is used and obviously only sets the fields I gave it with DataTable. So the solution is to set

```
$this->paginate = array(
'fields' => array('Post.*')
);
```

In fron of any paginate()-calls. Thanks Scrappy Cocco for giving the hint with the asterisk.